# Facing ORA-01830 Error when Selecting data from ORACLE database

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

I have problem when trying to select records from Oracle database using WPF.
I got this error : ORA-01830(date format picture ends before converting entire input string
Cause)

My code:

```
OracleDataReader dr;
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection() { ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE=*****:1521/ORCL;PASSWORD=*****;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=*****" })
{
    cn.Open();

    // DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(from_datePicker.Text);
    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter("Select B_NO,R_CLIENT_NAME,ENG_NAME,USER_NAME,R_ADDRESS,R_WORK_DATE,B_DATE,B_YEAR,B_WP_NAME,I_NAME,I_NO,BI_Q,I_CONTSR_TYPE_DESCR,R_PLACE_DESCR from VW_CI_REP_ITEMS_RESERV  where R_WORK_DATE = '" + from_datePicker.SelectedDate + "'", cn);

    DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds2, "VW_CI_REP_ITEMS_RESERV");

    DeltaInvoices_Grid.ItemsSource = ds2.Tables["VW_CI_REP_ITEMS_RESERV"].DefaultView;
}

GridCount_txt.Text = DeltaInvoices_Grid.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
      OracleDataReader dr;
      using (OracleConnection cn = new OracleConnection() { ConnectionString = "DATA SOURCE=*****:1521/ORCL;PASSWORD=*****;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=*****" })
      {
        cn.Open();

        var sql =
          "Select B_NO,R_CLIENT_NAME,ENG_NAME,USER_NAME,R_ADDRESS,R_WORK_DATE,B_DATE,B_YEAR,B_WP_NAME,I_NAME,I_NO,BI_Q,I_CONTSR_TYPE_DESCR,R_PLACE_DESCR from VW_CI_REP_ITEMS_RESERV  where R_WORK_DATE = :fromDatePicker";

        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, cn);
        var parameter = new OracleParameter("fromDatePicker", OracleDbType.Date) {
          Value = Convert.ToDateTime(from_datePicker.Text),

        };

        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds2, "VW_CI_REP_ITEMS_RESERV");

        DeltaInvoices_Grid.ItemsSource = ds2.Tables["VW_CI_REP_ITEMS_RESERV"].DefaultView;
      }

      GridCount_txt.Text = DeltaInvoices_Grid.Items.Count.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter an ORA-01830 error, the following error message will appear:

ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
Cause
You tried to enter a date value, but the date entered did not match the date format.

I think you should convert the "Date" field you are passing to oracle data adapter like this:

```
 TO_DATE(from_datePicker.SelectedDate, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh:mi PM')
```

or any other format that you have saved this field in your database.

Comment: thanks for your replay but i got another error : The name 'TO_DATE' does not exist in the current context

Comment: please  write the code you put in OracleDataAdapter (with to_date)